# Wordpress plugin internationalization: variables not translated?

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization, gettext

I have a wordpress plugin with some settings stored in an array with a slug and a label for each setting.

My plugin is class based, and this is the code of my construct function

```
class My_Plugin {
  function __construct() {
    $this->_options = array(
        'optionA' => __( 'Text for first option', 'my-plugin' ),
        'optionB' => __( 'Text for second option', 'my-plugin' ),
        'optionC' => __( 'Text for third option', 'my-plugin' ),
    );
  }
}
```

I use a similar structure in few places, to store a list of values associated with a label with get text. For example, later on, this array could be used to create a form with user settings

```
foreach ($this->_options as $option_name => $option_label) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="' . $option_name .  '" value="' . $option_label . '"/>';
}
```

I use a similar structure elsewhere as well.
Now, the strange (?) thing I noticed is that when I translate the plugin using PoEdit, these strings are not translated.
Why does that happen? Is there anything I could do, aside from changing the structure and directly write each input field, or repetitive structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand how gettext libraries (including the one in WordPress) work — once you do, the cause of issues like this is easy to reason about:

`__()` is not some magic marker, but a plain old function. It takes a string as its input, searches the *currently loaded* MO file for the domain, *if there’s any*, and returns a translation if it finds one. Otherwise it returns the input unmodified (i.e. falling back to English).

So the question you need to ask yourself, with the knowledge of the rest of your code that you didn’t include here, is: Was the translation for the `my-plugin` domain loaded *at the time when `__()` was called from the constructors?*

A reasonable guess is that no, it was not. You first constructed the `My_Plugin` object, thus calling `__()` when no translations were loaded and the gettext library wasn’t yet properly initialized. In such situation, the only thing the function can do is return the original English string. At some point *later* (chronologically, not necessarily in source code order) your gettext initialization hook was executed and called `load_plugin_textdomain`. From that point on, `__()` would behave as expected. That was too late for your constructor, though, because you *already* “translated” these strings.

It’s perfectly fine to store translated values as you do (although it’s also a bit pointless, because it doesn’t give you any meaningful performance benefits). But you need to rigorously follow a simple rule: **Load translations first, *then* use them.**

Comment: I have a similar issue. In certain post transition hook I use these variables and pass them on to another function that sends an email. The translations are in EN instead of language set in WPLANG. load_textdomain happens before, so your solution unfortunately does not help. Do you have any other ideas perhaps? thanks!